# Test out of range

Tags: c++

I am trying to test if accessing an element in a string is out of range. I know how to catch(std::out_of_range) but what im trying to do is if(out_of_range)
Example:

```
string test;
int a;
test="123456789";
if(test.at(9)==out_of_range) //this isnt proper code but this is what im trying to accomplish
{
a=0;}
else
a=1;
```

I am programming in C++ VS10

Comment: Exceptions have to be caught. An exception thrown by a function is completely separate from and unrelated to its normal return type. That's why you can't check for it with `if (function() == exception)`.

Comment: I realized as soon as I asked it thats what I have to do, i feel like an idiot lol

Answer (score 1):

The 'range' of a string is it's size. if there is 1 character in it, then it's size() is 1. So you could do

if(test.size() < 9)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just check the length of the string ?